# How do I return all records from a table if there is no record in filter table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a multi-select box in the front-end from which user selects multiple customer names. I have the system save customer names that user selects into another table, then use the IN operator to use the values from this filter table to pull records from other tables. If no customer name selected by user (thus no record saved into the filter table) then I want to return all records. I have tried it many different ways but can't get it to work correctly. Using `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause doesn't seem to work at all either.

To show a very simplified version (my actual code gathers data from several different tables), 
below is a code that returns data from table `tmp_CustShipments`, based on the filter list in `tbl_CustSelect`. It works when user makes selections.

But, when user makes no selection, I want to return all records from `tmp_CustShipments` table.
How do I achieve this?

If (`IF ... ELSE ...`) is used, then system seems to expect different table names for the "into" section, otherwise SQL will return an error saying the table already exists.  This will make it very messy since the result set has to be used as an input for further, more complex calculations in subsequent queries.

```
SELECT a.*   
into #qry_ShipStat
FROM #tmp_CustShipments a
WHERE a.CustName IN (SELECT Cust FROM dbo.tbl_CustSelect)
```

Please help if you can. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a NOT EXISTS clause.

```
SELECT a.*   
into #qry_ShipStat
FROM #tmp_CustShipments a
WHERE a.CustName IN (SELECT Cust FROM dbo.tbl_CustSelect)
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT Cust FROM dbo.tbl_CustSelect)
```